# Issue while generating watermark image using imagemagick Java

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, watermark

Hi iam trying to generate image with watermark using imagemagick, I have used the below command

```
composite -compose atop -geometry +400 -gravity southeast E:/imagesWaterMarkTest/watermark.png E:/imagesWaterMarkTest/photo.jpg E:/imagesWaterMarkTest/photoAfter.jpg
```

when iam generating using command prompt its working fine and generating image with watermark

But it fails when i generate using Java it is generating two images photoAfter-0.jpg(Plain watermark image) and photoAfter-1.jpg(Plain image), I don't understand whats wrong can any once suggest any changes.

Here is my code

```
try {
      String command =  StringBuffer().append(tool)
    .append(" composite -compose atop -geometry +400 -gravity southeast ").append(waterMarkImageSrcFile).append(" ")//Watermark Image source
    .append(srcFile).append(" ") //Original Image file path
    .append(destFile).toString();//Destination File path
        log.equals("Info: Generating watermark image: " + command);
        System.out.println("Info: Generating watermark image using: " + command);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

Comment: What is the result of the Sysout for the command? Are you getting any errors? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: This is the output of sysout (no errors)

Info: Generating watermark image using: C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/convert composite -compose atop -geometry +400 -gravity southeast C:/images/test/watermark.png C:\images\test\67434.jpg C:/123.jpg

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

`This is the output of sysout (no errors) Info: Generating watermark image using: C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/convert composite -compose atop -geometry +400 -gravity southeast C:/images/test/watermark.png C:\images\test\67434.jpg C:/123.jpg –`

Note that the files are indicating different paths:

Instead of `C:/images/test/watermark.png`, it should be `C:\images\test\watermark.png`
Instead of `C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/convert', it should be`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert`

This could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Made changes as u have suggested no luck !! :(